# easyrule-nar file is not adding any process to nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, easy-rules

I am using nifi 1.12.1 version

I was trying use easyrule rule engine in nifi hence downloaded a nar file **nifi-easyrules-nar-1.13.2.2.1.1.0-13.nar** from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-easyrules-nar/1.13.2.2.1.1.0-13

Copied the same nar file to lib directory inside nifi-1.12.1 folder and started nifi server.

But easyrules process is not adding to nifi process. No of process before and after adding easyrule-nar is 288 only. which are built-in processes.

But I tried adding some other custom nar it added properly and I am able to see the process as well.

Can someone suggest me why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Check a site:

http://lonnifi.blogspot.com/2020/01/rules-integration-with-apache-nifi.html

> Default rules functionality is not available in the NiFi pre-built binaries, so  developers, or other brave NiFi users, will need to build from source and ensure to include the rules profile as shown below:
>
> `mvn -T C2.0 clean install -Pinclude-grpc,include-rules`